# How to edit WordPress Roles

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I am using Wordpress 3.0.2, i have to create 2 new roles:

1) User can only edit post.

2) User can edit posts & add post to Drafts (Should not publish)

I have gone thorugh some plugins, but did not find a way to do the 2nd one, ie create a user role with capability to only add a new post to draft, Hope some one could help me with this..
(I am using wordpress for the first time so doesnt no much)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already there http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

> Contributor - Somebody who can write and manage their posts but not publish them

Comment: I want to create a user with conrtibutor capability and also who can edit all posts. so is that possible?? i just tried role scoper plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/), as i said am just using wordpress for the first time and there are too many options which am not able to understand, is there any simple plugins which is compatible with my Wordpress version.

Comment: You want a user to be able to edit all post not only his own posts?
That's not there by default but everything is possible with wordpress, And role-scoper seems to do the trick, add a new user group via 'Role Groups' then go to wp-admin/admin.php?page=rs-post-roles and give the group 'Post Editor' privileges.

Comment: i went to wp-admin/admin.php?page=rs-options, edited post conrtributor role so that he can only add post but not publish it, and edit all posts, and now from wp-admin/admin.php?page=rs-post-roles assigned the new gropu as post contributor.. is that how it should be..

Comment: ok how am i supposed to add a new user to a new group, to give him role, while adding new user there doesnot show the new gropu i added..

Comment: You first add a user normally wp-admin/user-new.php, then go to /wp-admin/admin.php?page=rs-post-roles and chose him from the 'eligible users' and give him 'Post Editor'

Comment: Found another one which is totally better. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/ it lets you edit current user groups, install it and it's alot easier.

Comment: yes this one is very simple & easy to  use, but whatever level i give and new user i created with all edit capabilities cant edit admin's posts

Comment: Yes it doesn't mess with admin privilege.

Comment: mm yes but requirement needs dat also , but its ok will manage it.. anyway thanks a lot :-)